# DateTime format changes after publishing c# VS 2013

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am having a crazy issue after publishing to IIS.
It is a c# application, all the globalization written by the books.
Date and time settings are exactly the same on my laptop and my Windows 2008 Server control panels. Both machines are configured to MM/dd/yyyy.

Running the app on my notebook (dev) date is listed as MM/dd/yyyy.
Running the app on the server (prod) date is listed as M/d/yyyy.

On web.config

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" enableClientBasedCulture="false"></globalization>
```

On IIS, website properties:

- Open .NET GLOBALIZATION
- From Culture tab, selected required Culture and UI Culture. It is there: en-US

I've changed event on the registry 
folder:

1. `HKEY_USERS -> .DEFAULT -> Control Panel -> International`
2. Right click on key `sShortDate`, click `Modify`
3. Change the `Value` data to MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: "The books" tend to be outdated fast. Show relevant code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. It works, the only thing is that data is listed on my notebook llike this 
MM/dd/yyyy
and on the server
M/d/yyyy